# Adding a core data object to an array without saving it to core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm creating a scheduling app that has the ability for the user to make an event repeat. Events are stored in core data and they have a String attribute to denote its repetition interval.

I handle repetition as follows:

1. Load the all of the core data events into an array
2. Loop through the array of event objects and check to see if the event repeats
3. If the event does repeat, a new event object it to the array of events, but don't save it to core data.

Right now I am using:

```
for week in 1 ... 53 {

    let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    let newEvent = Event(context: childContext)

    newEvent.title = event.title
    newEvent.eventDescrip = event.eventDescrip
    newEvent.moveable = event.moveable
    newEvent.eventType = event.eventType
    newEvent.repetitionInterval = event.repetitionInterval
    newEvent.alertTime = event.alertTime
    newEvent.startTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: week, to: event.startTime!)
    newEvent.endTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: week, to: event.endTime!)

    self.allEvents.append(newEvent)
}
```

to try and make the new event which works, but when I add it to the array, all of its attributes become nil.

Anyone know how I can solve this or a better way to do it?

Comment: This is just a guess, but creating a childcontext for every entity, that also goes out of scope after adding the entity to the array, seems to be at least part of the problem.

Comment: How does your app consume the repeating events? Will the app show multiple events (on a calendar for example), does it generate timed notifications, will it show only the next event, ...?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- Store the repetition interval in CoreData as a `Double`, which is the same as [`TimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timeinterval).  In that way you can easily create event `Date` objects.  This also allows you to do CoreData searches (see following point) to expiry time, for example: 'get all events that will occur in the following 10 minutes'.
- Use an `NSFetchRequest` with `NSPredicate`(s) to retrieve the required array of CoreData event objects.
- Have non-CoreData structures (general term, not meaning `struct`) for further processing of the retrieved events.  The information stored in CoreData describes when events occur, the actual 'execution' of events is something different.  It's good practice to keep (semantically) different things apart, because *meaning matters*.